Non-Parametric Regression: Seminal Papers
This question is mostly a question for references and is not objectively answerable as recommendations for literature inherently depend on personal preference. I hope it is still ok.
I would like to ask, what you would consider seminal/important papers in non-parametric regression? The backround of the question is that I am conducting research on a specific aspect of non-parametric regression without knowing too much about it in general. Before diving in too deep into a specific direction, I would like to have some recommendations.

Thank you, I know about this stack. However, I have always felt that non-parametric regression is often investigated by mathematicians... but maybe my intuition is misled. Should there be no answers to the question on this stack, I will try to ask on the statistics one!

A classic mathematical statistics reference is Stone 1982, which establishes the minimax nonparametric rate of convergence.
This is an essential reference to understand if you want to prove asymptotic properties about some nonparametric method.

Thank you! My current research isnt necessarily about asymptotics, but I think its still beneficial for me to try to understand the paper. I heard about this paper before. Can I ask you one question about it? When reading about the $m$-th order derivative, for which the optimal rates are derived, I immediately have to think about the taylor expansion of the regression function, $\theta$. So my intuition is that the optimal rates on the derivatives translate to optimal rates on the function itself. Is this intuition/interpretation justified?

That sounds like a new question ...

@Glen_b certainly it would be interesting to address this as a separate question but the short answer is...

@Red ... that the function itself may be viewed as the zero'th derivative, such that the results in that article hold for the function (when m=0 in their notation).
